# Windows 10 "Display settings could not be saved" Preventing Multiple Monitors from working

Tags: windows-10, display, multiple-monitors

I've had a three monitor setup for more than a month now. Once I get it initially working, it is quite reliable. It seems that every time I need to reboot my computer for one reason or another all settings are lost and I have to go through initial setup pains again including Windows detecting but not displaying anything on either one, two, or all three of the monitors.

I'm using a work issued Dell Latitude 5424 with its docking station, have three dell U2515 daisy chained through a single displayport chain. Right now, only the final monitor in the chain is functioning, though the USB ports on the other two monitors are working correctly (keyboard plugged into monitor 2 of 3 which has no signal).

In windows display settings all three monitors show up, though 1 and 2 appear smaller than 3 which is active at full resolution. When I select 1 or 2, it's set to "Disconnect this display". Whether I select duplicate or extend in any combination, I get the response "The display settings could not be saved. Please try a different combination of display settings." and the monitor is returned to "Disconnect this display".

I've tried changing resolutions and nearly every other setting in the windows display settings menu. I've run the windows troubleshooters and scanned for hardware changes, with no results and nothing to fix found. I've power cycled all three monitors individually and all at once through the power strip they are all plugged into. I've done multiple computer reboots. The Intel Graphics control panel shows the same thing as the Windows display settings, the first and second monitors are present but not active. Both monitors that are blank say they have no signal from the computer.

I actually haven't tried re-installing display drivers, but they are at the latest level available. I find it strange that once things start working again, I can un-dock and re-dock without issues, it seems I only have this issue after a system reboot. The last couple times I don't know what actually fixed this issue. One of them it fixed itself when I docked again, another time I had put the computer to sleep overnight and when I woke it up the next morning suddenly all monitors were working again.

Intel UHD Graphics 620, Windows 10 Enterprise 64 bit.

I'm at a loss for what is causing Windows to not allow usage of these monitors, and don't understand why they will at some point suddenly start working with no hardware or software configuration changes. Any help is appreciated!

> [image]

Comment: A few more troubleshooting hint: Disconnect everything but your primary monitor, and hook it up directly. Download the latest display drivers from either Intel or Dell Support. Uninstall all of the display adapters shown in device manager and install your new drivers. Hook up the monitors one at a time, saving your desired placement for that monitor each time you add one. Try, different cables to different monitors in a different order. Try to flip the cables. Try generating an "Intel Graphics Drivers report" to see if it gives you any clues.